# Adding an element to a list every second element

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to insert an element to an existing list every second element.

Let's say the list is `fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]`, to add the element `"peach"` what I do is:

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]
fruits_2 = list(fruits)

for i in range(len(fruits)):
    fruits_2.insert(2*i + 1, "peach")

print(fruits_2)
```

and the output is

```
['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

which is what I want, but I feel like there is probably a better and more concise way to do this, without creating a second list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip`, along with `itertools.repeat` and `itertools.chain`.

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(fruits, repeat("peach"))))
['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

`repeat` creates an infinite sequence of `'peach'`. `zip` creates a sequence of pairs, consisting of one item from fruits followed by an instance of `'peach'`. `chain.from_iterable` "flattens" the sequence of pairs into a single sequence, and `list` produces a concrete list from the sequence.

---

Looking at the intermediate steps:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> list(islice(repeat("peaches"), 5))
['peaches', 'peaches', 'peaches', 'peaches', 'peaches']

>>> zip(fruits, repeat("peaches"))
[('banana', 'peaches'), ('apple', 'peaches'), ('mango', 'peaches'), ('kiwi', 'peaches')]
```

---

This approach boils down to a series of `appends` to a new list, something like

```
result = []
for x in fruits:
    result.append(x)
    result.append("peaches")
```

But instead of hard-coding the arguments to `append`, you fetch them from a pair of iterators:

```
def peach_source():
    while True:
        yield "peach"

def fruit_source(fruits):
    for x in fruits:
        yield x

result = []
peaches = peach_source()
fruits = fruit_source(fruits)  # Yes, this is highly redundant; just showing the similarity to peach_source
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        result.append(next(fruits))
    except StopIteration:
        done = True
    result.append(next(peaches))
```

`itertools.repeat` creates `peach_source` for you. `zip` handle the alternation between fetching a fruit and fetching a peach. `chain.from_iterable` defines the action of appending to `result`, and `list` actually *executes* the appends.

Comment: I was playing around with something similar, but I'm not sure I grasp the complexity vs. the sequential inserts which require diminishing remaining elements to be shifted in the original approach with `insert`. Is this actually more efficient in terms of complexity?

Comment: `zip` basically just alternates calling `next` on the two sequences, something like `while True: yield next(fruits); yield next(peaches)`; once the shorter sequence is exhausted, the loop terminates. Basically, nothing happens until you actually start to consume the iterator using `list`; until then, you are just queuing up the instructions to create the sequence.

Comment: Ah, so a series of appends rather than inserts, being O(1) instead of the O(n) of insert

Answer (score 2):

Simply with "*double-length*" (and even/odd position) magic:

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]
new_fruits = [fruits[i // 2] if i % 2 == 0 else 'peach' for i in range(len(fruits) * 2)]
print(new_fruits)
```

The output:

```
['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

---

If proceeding with `itertools` approaches `itertools.zip_longest` feature seems to be the most fast:

```
new_fruits = [v for v in itertools.zip_longest(fruits, add, fillvalue=add[0])]
```

*Timings:*

```
In [33]: fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]                                                      

In [34]: add = ["peach"]                                                                                    

In [35]: %timeit [v for v in itertools.zip_longest(fruits, add, fillvalue=add[0])]                          
859 ns ± 16.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [36]: %timeit list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(fruits, itertools.repeat(*add))))                   
992 ns ± 40.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [37]: %timeit list(itertools.chain(*itertools.product(fruits, add)))                                     
1.05 µs ± 18 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [38]: %timeit [i for s in [[f, *add] for f in fruits] for i in s]                                        
1.25 µs ± 73.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit [fruits[i // 2] if i % 2 == 0 else "peach" for i in range(len(fruits) * 2)]                
1.29 µs ± 12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

list comprehension + flattening option - no imports needed:

```py
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]
add = 'peach'
out = [i for s in [[f, add] for f in fruits] for i in s]
out
# ['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

itertools product option:

```py
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]
add = ["peach"]
out = list(itertools.chain(*itertools.product(fruits, add)))
out
# ['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

some timings:

```py
%timeit list(chain.from_iterable(zip(fruits, repeat(*add))))
910 ns ± 19.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit list(itertools.chain(*itertools.product(fruits, add)))
1.07 µs ± 13.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit [fruits[i // 2] if i % 2 == 0 else "peach" for i in range(len(fruits) * 2)]
1.62 µs ± 40.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%timeit [i for s in [[f, *add] for f in fruits] for i in s]
2.16 µs ± 630 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**however, the fastest option seems to be the simplest:**

```py
def func(fruits):
    result = []
    for x in fruits:
        result.append(x)
        result.append("peaches")
    return result

%timeit func(fruits)
746 ns ± 15.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you did but on the first list:

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]
for i in range(len(fruits)):
    fruits.insert(i*2+1, "peach")

>>> fruits
['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert an element in a list every second element, i recommend this code :

```
fruits = ["banana", "apple", "mango", "kiwi"]

for x in range(len(fruits), 0 , -1):
    fruits.insert(x, "peach")
```

You'll get this result

```
['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'peach', 'mango', 'peach', 'kiwi', 'peach']
```

Don't try to make a comprehension list from this code. It will not work.